# Flutter ListView CastError only on Hot Reload

Tags: flutter, dart

I notify a very strange bug in my Flutter app. I'm using a `ListView` with an `itemExtend` value. When navigating inside the app everything is working fine – no error messages in the console. But after a Hot Reload, for example by editing and saving the code on the file on which the ListView is placed, I get many `RenderRepaintBoundary` errors.

This is my ListView:

```
return ListView.builder(
  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 25, bottom: 20),
  shrinkWrap: true,
  itemExtent: 95, // Error only appears if I add itemExtent
  physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
  itemCount: entriesController.guestbookEntries.length,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {

    return GestureDetector(
      onLongPress: () async {
        // Some stuff
      },
      child: Text("Test Widget")
    );
  },
);
```

After Hot Reload I get the following error messages in the console (But the app works as expected):

> [Easy Localization] Build [Easy Localization] Init Localization
> Delegate [Easy Localization] Init provider
>
> ════════ Exception caught by rendering library
> ═════════════════════════════════ The following _CastError was thrown
> during performLayout(): Null check operator used on a null value
>
> The relevant error-causing widget was ListView When the exception was
> thrown, this was the stack
> #0      RenderSliverFixedExtentBoxAdaptor.performLayout
> #1      RenderObject.layout
> #2      RenderSliverEdgeInsetsPadding.performLayout
> #3      RenderSliverPadding.performLayout
> #4      RenderObject.layout ... The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired:
> RenderSliverFixedExtentList#b073b relayoutBoundary=up11 NEEDS-LAYOUT
> NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE RenderObject:
> RenderSliverFixedExtentList#b073b relayoutBoundary=up11 NEEDS-LAYOUT
> NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
> needs compositing
> parentData: paintOffset=Offset(0.0, 25.0) (can use size)
> constraints: SliverConstraints(AxisDirection.down, GrowthDirection.forward, ScrollDirection.idle, scrollOffset: 0.0,
> remainingPaintExtent: Infinity, crossAxisExtent: 390.0,
> crossAxisDirection: AxisDirection.right, viewportMainAxisExtent:
> Infinity, remainingCacheExtent: Infinity, cacheOrigin: 0.0)
> geometry: SliverGeometry(scrollExtent: 760.0, paintExtent: 760.0, maxPaintExtent: 760.0, cacheExtent: 760.0)
> scrollExtent: 760.0
> paintExtent: 760.0
> maxPaintExtent: 760.0
> cacheExtent: 760.0
> currently live children: 0 to 7
> child with index 0: RenderIndexedSemantics#56371 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
> needs compositing
> parentData: index=0; layoutOffset=0.0
> constraints: BoxConstraints(w=390.0, h=95.0)
> semantic boundary
> size: Size(390.0, 95.0)
> index: 0
> child: RenderRepaintBoundary#1056f NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
> needs compositing
> parentData:  (can use size)
> constraints: BoxConstraints(w=390.0, h=95.0)
> layer: OffsetLayer#9f74a
> engine layer: OffsetEngineLayer#9b21b
> offset: Offset(0.0, 25.0)
> size: Size(390.0, 95.0)
> metrics: 83.3% useful (1 bad vs 5 good)
> diagnosis: this is a useful repaint boundary and should be kept
> child: RenderSemanticsGestureHandler#c0c8b NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
> parentData:  (can use size)
> constraints: BoxConstraints(w=390.0, h=95.0)
> size: Size(390.0, 95.0)
> gestures: long press
> child: RenderPointerListener#c4b22 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
> parentData:  (can use size)
> constraints: BoxConstraints(w=390.0, h=95.0)
> size: Size(390.0, 95.0)
> behavior: deferToChild
> listeners: down
> child with index 1: RenderIndexedSemantics#c082a NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
> needs compositing
> parentData: index=1; layoutOffset=95.0
> constraints: BoxConstraints(w=390.0, h=95.0)
> semantic boundary
> size: Size(390.0, 95.0)
> index: 1
> child: RenderRepaintBoundary#f5bbf NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
> needs compositing
> parentData:  (can use size)
> constraints: BoxConstraints(w=390.0, h=95.0)
> layer: OffsetLayer#003b7
> engine layer: OffsetEngineLayer#75c0b
> offset: Offset(0.0, 120.0)
> size: Size(390.0, 95.0)
> metrics: 83.3% useful (1 bad vs 5 good)
> diagnosis: this is a useful repaint boundary and should be kept
> child: RenderSemanticsGestureHandler#eee56 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
> parentData:  (can use size)
> constraints: BoxConstraints(w=390.0, h=95.0)
> size: Size(390.0, 95.0)
> gestures: long press
> child: RenderPointerListener#82ca0 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
> parentData:  (can use size)
> constraints: BoxConstraints(w=390.0, h=95.0)
> size: Size(390.0, 95.0)
> behavior: deferToChild
> listeners: down
> child with index 2: RenderIndexedSemantics#dc0db NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
> needs compositing
> parentData: index=2; layoutOffset=190.0
> constraints: BoxConstraints(w=390.0, h=95.0)
> semantic boundary
> size: Size(390.0, 95.0)
> index: 2
> child: RenderRepaintBoundary#394b9 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
> needs compositing
> parentData:  (can use size)
> constraints: BoxConstraints(w=390.0, h=95.0)
> layer: OffsetLayer#19e8a
> engine layer: OffsetEngineLayer#11d00
> offset: Offset(0.0, 215.0)
> size: Size(390.0, 95.0)
> metrics: 83.3% useful (1 bad vs 5 good)
> diagnosis: this is a useful repaint boundary and should be kept
> child: RenderSemanticsGestureHandler#0a954 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
> parentData:  (can use size)
> constraints: BoxConstraints(w=390.0, h=95.0)
> size: Size(390.0, 95.0)
> gestures: long press
> child: RenderPointerListener#d9fec NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
> parentData:  (can use size)
> constraints: BoxConstraints(w=390.0, h=95.0)
> size: Size(390.0, 95.0)
> behavior: deferToChild
> listeners: down
> child with index 3: RenderIndexedSemantics#7cad9 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
> needs compositing
> parentData: index=3; layoutOffset=285.0
> constraints: BoxConstraints(w=390.0, h=95.0)
> semantic boundary
> size: Size(390.0, 95.0)
> index: 3
> child: RenderRepaintBoundary#6e0bd NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
> needs compositing
> parentData:  (can use size)
> constraints: BoxConstraints(w=390.0, h=95.0)
> layer: OffsetLayer#cacc4
> engine layer: OffsetEngineLayer#8785f
> offset: Offset(0.0, 310.0)
> size: Size(390.0, 95.0)
> metrics: 83.3% useful (1 bad vs 5 good)
> diagnosis: this is a useful repaint boundary and should be kept
> child: RenderSemanticsGestureHandler#0f21d NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
> parentData:  (can use size)
> constraints: BoxConstraints(w=390.0, h=95.0)
> size: Size(390.0, 95.0)
> gestures: long press
> child: RenderPointerListener#90d32 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
> parentData:  (can use size)
> constraints: BoxConstraints(w=390.0, h=95.0)
> size: Size(390.0, 95.0)
> behavior: deferToChild
> listeners: down
> child with index 4: RenderIndexedSemantics#98e3a NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
> needs compositing
> parentData: index=4; layoutOffset=380.0
> constraints: BoxConstraints(w=390.0, h=95.0)
> semantic boundary
> size: Size(390.0, 95.0)
> index: 4
> child: RenderRepaintBoundary#4b651 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
> needs compositing
> parentData:  (can use size)
> constraints: BoxConstraints(w=390.0, h=95.0)
> layer: OffsetLayer#4d349
> engine layer: OffsetEngineLayer#3ac9d
> offset: Offset(0.0, 405.0)
> size: Size(390.0, 95.0)
> metrics: 83.3% useful (1 bad vs 5 good)
> diagnosis: this is a useful repaint boundary and should be kept
> child: RenderSemanticsGestureHandler#d08c0 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
> parentData:  (can use size)
> constraints: BoxConstraints(w=390.0, h=95.0)
> size: Size(390.0, 95.0)
> gestures: long press
> child: RenderPointerListener#4d447 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
> parentData:  (can use size)
> constraints: BoxConstraints(w=390.0, h=95.0)
> size: Size(390.0, 95.0)
> behavior: deferToChild
> listeners: down
> child with index 5: RenderIndexedSemantics#3c29c NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
> needs compositing
> parentData: index=5; layoutOffset=475.0
> constraints: BoxConstraints(w=390.0, h=95.0)
> semantic boundary
> size: Size(390.0, 95.0)
> index: 5
> child: RenderRepaintBoundary#95d2d NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
> needs compositing
> parentData:  (can use size)
> constraints: BoxConstraints(w=390.0, h=95.0)
> layer: OffsetLayer#0a5f6
> engine layer: OffsetEngineLayer#48bb1
> offset: Offset(0.0, 500.0)
> size: Size(390.0, 95.0)
> metrics: 83.3% useful (1 bad vs 5 good)
> diagnosis: this is a useful repaint boundary and should be kept
> child: RenderSemanticsGestureHandler#9d4f2 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
> parentData:  (can use size)
> constraints: BoxConstraints(w=390.0, h=95.0)
> size: Size(390.0, 95.0)
> gestures: long press
> child: RenderPointerListener#41da2 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
> parentData:  (can use size)
> constraints: BoxConstraints(w=390.0, h=95.0)
> size: Size(390.0, 95.0)
> behavior: deferToChild
> listeners: down
> child with index 6: RenderIndexedSemantics#97f8c NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
> needs compositing
> parentData: index=6; layoutOffset=570.0
> constraints: BoxConstraints(w=390.0, h=95.0)
> semantic boundary
> size: Size(390.0, 95.0)
> index: 6
> child: RenderRepaintBoundary#43698 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
> needs compositing
> parentData:  (can use size)
> constraints: BoxConstraints(w=390.0, h=95.0)
> layer: OffsetLayer#4c73b
> engine layer: OffsetEngineLayer#cf9c5
> offset: Offset(0.0, 595.0)
> size: Size(390.0, 95.0)
> metrics: 83.3% useful (1 bad vs 5 good)
> diagnosis: this is a useful repaint boundary and should be kept
> child: RenderSemanticsGestureHandler#a439c NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
> parentData:  (can use size)
> constraints: BoxConstraints(w=390.0, h=95.0)
> size: Size(390.0, 95.0)
> gestures: long press
> child: RenderPointerListener#c1b95 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
> parentData:  (can use size)
> constraints: BoxConstraints(w=390.0, h=95.0)
> size: Size(390.0, 95.0)
> behavior: deferToChild
> listeners: down
> child with index 7: RenderIndexedSemantics#af472 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
> needs compositing
> parentData: index=7; layoutOffset=665.0
> constraints: BoxConstraints(w=390.0, h=95.0)
> semantic boundary
> size: Size(390.0, 95.0)
> index: 7
> child: RenderRepaintBoundary#af250 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
> needs compositing
> parentData:  (can use size)
> constraints: BoxConstraints(w=390.0, h=95.0)
> layer: OffsetLayer#45ab6
> engine layer: OffsetEngineLayer#f6a96
> offset: Offset(0.0, 690.0)
> size: Size(390.0, 95.0)
> metrics: 83.3% useful (1 bad vs 5 good)
> diagnosis: this is a useful repaint boundary and should be kept
> child: RenderSemanticsGestureHandler#aac55 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
> parentData:  (can use size)
> constraints: BoxConstraints(w=390.0, h=95.0)
> size: Size(390.0, 95.0)
> gestures: long press
> child: RenderPointerListener#428a8 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
> parentData:  (can use size)
> constraints: BoxConstraints(w=390.0, h=95.0)
> size: Size(390.0, 95.0)
> behavior: deferToChild
> listeners: down ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
> Reloaded 67 of 2009 libraries in 683ms.

Do you have an idea what happens here and why without Hot Reload everything works fine? And how to fix such an error? I tried to remove the `itemExtend`. Then it works and the error does not appear. But without itemExtend I have some flickering in my ListView. Looks like order changing or something else. Its very ugly. Therefore I need to itemExtend to fix it.

If you need a better view of the code context, I send you the code of the entire file. By the way. There are still no gos like handling data inside a build method. Its an old project and I'm on the way to rewrite it entirely. But this things are not responsible for the error. It is interesting, that the error does not appear when I remove "itemExtend". How is that possible?

The entire code:

```
class GuestGuestbookContent extends StatelessWidget {
  GuestGuestbookContent({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  GuestbooksController get guestbooksController => Get.find();
  EntriesController get entriesController => Get.find();
  UsersController get usersController => Get.find();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SliverToBoxAdapter(
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50, top: 50),
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: entriesController.obx((state) {
          return Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                child: MixinBuilder(
                  initState: (_) async {
                    await entriesController.checkGuestbookForUserEntries(
                        guestbooksController.currentGuestbook.value.id);
                  },
                  builder: (_) {
                    if (entriesController.hasUserEntry.value == true) {
                      return Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            padding:
                                const EdgeInsets.only(left: 25.0, right: 25),
                            child: Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              children: [
                                Text("your_entries",
                                        style: Get.theme.textTheme.headline4)
                                    .tr(),
                                IconButton(
                                    alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                                    icon: Icon(
                                      entriesController.showOwnEntries.value ==
                                              false
                                          ? CupertinoIcons.arrow_down
                                          : CupertinoIcons.arrow_up,
                                      color: Get.theme.colorScheme.primary,
                                      size: 20,
                                    ),
                                    onPressed: () => entriesController
                                            .showOwnEntries.value =
                                        !entriesController.showOwnEntries.value)
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          entriesController.showOwnEntries.value == true
                              ? _buildUserEntries()
                              : Container(),
                          SizedBox(height: 15),
                        ],
                      );
                    } else {
                      bool isOpen = true;
                      DateTime startDate;
                      if (guestbooksController
                              .currentGuestbook.value.startDate !=
                          null) {
                        startDate = DateTime.parse(guestbooksController
                            .currentGuestbook.value.startDate);

                        isOpen = startDate.isAtSameMomentAs(DateTime.now()) ||
                            startDate.isBefore(DateTime.now());
                      }

                      if (isOpen) {
                        return _buildAddEntryButton();
                      } else {
                        return Container(
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              Image.asset("assets/animations/clock.gif",
                                  width:
                                      context.isTablet ? 400 : Get.width / 2),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 15,
                              ),
                              Text("guestbook_opens_at").tr(),
                              SizedBox(height: 5),
                              Text(
                                  DateFormat(tr("date_format"))
                                      .format(startDate),
                                  style: Get.theme.textTheme.headline1)
                            ],
                          ),
                        );
                      }
                    }
                  },
                ),
              ),

              // Alle Einträge
              guestbooksController.currentGuestbook.value.isPublic == true ||
                      _isModerator() == true
                  ? _buildAllEntriesContainer()
                  : Container(),
            ],
          );
        }, onLoading: LoadingSpinner()),
      ),
    );
  }

  bool _isModerator() {
    return usersController.userIsModerator(
        userID: usersController.ownUser.value.uid,
        guestbook: guestbooksController.currentGuestbook.value);
  }

  CupertinoButton _buildAddEntryButton() {
    return CupertinoButton(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Icon(
              Icons.add,
              size: 50,
            ),
            Text(
              "create_entry",
              style:
                  TextStyle(color: Get.theme.colorScheme.primary, fontSize: 20),
            ).tr(),
            SizedBox(height: 25),
          ],
        ),
        onPressed: () => Get.toNamed("writeNewEntry"));
  }

  ListView _buildUserEntries() {
    return ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0, bottom: 10),
        physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
        itemCount: entriesController.userEntriesData.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          final Entry entry = entriesController.userEntriesData[index];

          // Manage description
          String entryContent = "";
          List entryContentInput = [];
          if (entry.content != null) {
            final parsedContent = jsonDecode(entry.content);
            if (parsedContent != null) {
              for (int i = 0; i < parsedContent.length; i++) {
                entryContentInput.add(parsedContent[i]["insert"]);
              }
              entryContent = entryContentInput.join("").toString();
            }
          }

          return GestureDetector(
            onLongPress: () {
              _userEntryOptions(entry);
            },
            child: GuestListTile(
              entry: entry,
              description: entryContent != null && entryContent.isNotEmpty
                  ? entryContent
                  : tr("no_text_added"),
              owner: entry.owner,
              hasImages: entry.images != null && entry.images.isNotEmpty,
              hasVideos: entry.videos != null && entry.videos.isNotEmpty,
              hasPainting:
                  entry.paintingImage != null && entry.paintingImage.isNotEmpty,
            ),
          );
        });
  }

  Container _buildAllEntriesContainer() {
    return Container(
      child: MixinBuilder(
        builder: (EntriesController controller) {
          if (controller.guestbookEntriesWithoutOwn.length > 0) {
            return Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 25.0, right: 25),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Text("entries_from_all_guests",
                              style: Get.theme.textTheme.headline4)
                          .tr(),
                      CircleAvatar(
                        radius: 10,
                        backgroundColor: Get.theme.colorScheme.primary,
                        child: Text(
                            controller.guestbookEntriesWithoutOwn.length
                                .toString(),
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 10,
                                color: Get.theme.colorScheme.background)),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                _buildAllEntries(controller.guestbookEntriesWithoutOwn),
              ],
            );
          } else {
            return Container();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildAllEntries(List<Entry> entries) {
    if (entries != null && entries.isNotEmpty) {
      return ListView.builder(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 10),
          physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemExtent: 95,
          itemCount: entries.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            Entry entry;
            if (entries.length > 0) {
              entry = entries[index];

              // Manage description
              String entryContent = "";
              List entryContentInput = [];
              if (entry.content != null) {
                final parsedContent = jsonDecode(entry.content);
                if (parsedContent != null) {
                  for (int i = 0; i < parsedContent.length; i++) {
                    entryContentInput.add(parsedContent[i]["insert"]);
                  }
                  entryContent = entryContentInput.join("").toString();
                }
              }

              return GestureDetector(
                onLongPress: () async {
                  final userID = await getUid();
                  if (usersController.userIsModerator(
                          userID: userID,
                          guestbook:
                              guestbooksController.currentGuestbook.value) ==
                      true) {
                    _userEntryOptions(entry);
                  }
                },
                child: GuestListTile(
                  entry: entry,
                  description: entryContent != null &&
                          entryContent.isNotEmpty &&
                          entryContent != "\n"
                      ? entryContent
                      : tr("no_content"),
                  owner: entry.owner,
                  hasImages: entry.images != null && entry.images.isNotEmpty,
                  hasVideos: entry.videos != null && entry.videos.isNotEmpty,
                  hasPainting: entry.paintingImage != null &&
                      entry.paintingImage.isNotEmpty,
                ),
              );
            } else {
              return Container();
            }
          });
    } else {
      return Container();
    }
  }

  void _userEntryOptions(Entry entry) {
    Get.bottomSheet(CupertinoActionSheet(
      actions: [
        CupertinoActionSheetAction(
          onPressed: () {
            Get.back();
            _deleteUserEntryConfirmation(entry);
          },
          child: Text("delete_this_entry").tr(),
          isDestructiveAction: true,
        )
      ],
    ));
  }

  void _deleteUserEntryConfirmation(Entry entry) {
    Get.dialog(CupertinoAlertDialog(
      title: Text("delete_my_entry_desc").tr(),
      actions: [
        CupertinoDialogAction(
          child: Text("yes_delete_entry").tr(),
          isDestructiveAction: true,
          onPressed: () {
            Get.back();
            _deleteUserEntry(entry);
          },
        ),
        CupertinoDialogAction(
          child: Text("no_not_delete_entry").tr(),
          onPressed: () {
            Get.back();
          },
        )
      ],
    ));
  }

  void _deleteUserEntry(Entry entry) async {
    await entriesController.deleteEntireUserEntry(entry);
    await MySnackbar()
        .createSnackbar(message: tr("entry_deleted_successfully"), seconds: 2);
  }
}
```

By the way: I'm using the getx package for state management. This is the reason because I can go with a `Stateless` widget.

Comment: hot reload is similar with setstate and rebuild your widget, i think something become null after hot reload

Comment: Could you please add code for GuestListTile() or if not possible to share here, could you please try with replacing GuestListTile() with normal container and Text and check again?

Comment: Hi @ABV, I've added more code to the app. I've also tried it with a simple Text widget instead of the GuestListTile(). But the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Rebuild the app using the command `flutter clean`

Comment: Hi @Shamil, what's the reason for that? But no, badly the error is still showing, also after 'flutter clean' :(

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide a lot of code, but maybe you should try wrapping your `ListView.builder` with `Expanded` widget? :)

Then your code would become something like:

```
return Expanded(
 child: ListView.builder(
   padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 25, bottom: 20),
   shrinkWrap: true,
   itemExtent: 95,
   physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
   itemCount: entriesController.guestbookEntries.length,
   itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {

     return GestureDetector(
       onLongPress: () async {
         // Some stuff
       },
       child: GuestListTile()
     );
   },
));
```

The `Expanded` widget consumes available space which comes in handy if used in a `Column` or a `Row` -- you can read more about it @ [Flutter - Expanded](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html).

Comment: Many thanks, @IvanTheDevil, I've already tried the Expanded widget and is not working (same result). I've added more code above for a better view. Interesting that the error in the console only appears when `itemExtent` is included. By the way: the app works as aspected. The error is only showing in the console.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your `guestbookEntries` from `entriesController` variable is null when you do hot reload. Check the value if null show some loading indicator, then show the `ListView` when it's not null.

Your widget doesn't show anything much, because there is no controller class code.

Comment: Hi :) For the controller I'm using the StateMixin to show the data only when is loaded. I've doublechecked this. Also after refreshing I get the following print for `guestbookEntries.entriesController`: `flutter: [Instance of 'Entry', Instance of 'Entry', Instance of 'Entry', Instance of 'Entry', Instance of 'Entry', Instance of 'Entry', Instance of 'Entry', Instance of 'Entry', Instance of 'Entry', Instance of 'Entry', Instance of 'Entry', Instance of 'Entry', Instance of 'Entry', Instance of 'Entry', Instance of 'Entry', Instance of 'Entry', Instance of 'Entry', Instance of 'Entry']`

Comment: So the data is not null. Additional though: Why it works without the itemExtent value?

Comment: If `itemExtent` is non-null, `ListView` will forces the children to have the given extent in the scroll direction.

Answer (score 0):

Use this : Your Problem will be solved

---

```
        return Container(
    height: double.maxfinite;

             child:SingleChildScrollView(
         child: ListView.builder(
               padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 25, bottom: 20),
               shrinkWrap: true,
               itemExtent: 95,
               physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
               itemCount: entriesController.guestbookEntries.length,
               itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            
                 return GestureDetector(
                   onLongPress: () async {
                     // Some stuff
                   },
                   child: GuestListTile()
                 );
               },
            )));
```

Comment: Thanks, but no, the error still appears.

Comment: i have edited my answer kindly check with this

Comment: Still the same error. :(

Comment: If I do not use the `SingleChildScrollView`, but only the Container as wrapper with `height: double.maxFinite`, the error does not appear anymore! But: The height of the ListView is almost infinite. Its too long. What could I do to set the height dynamically?

Comment: put a controller in your listview and with this controller you can get the height of your listview and use this height as your container height . i hope you got it

Comment: The ScrollController() does not provide me a ListView height. In General seems like a workaround instead of a clean solution. There will be problems when new list items are inserted. Is difficult to change the height value everytime. I think we need a more robust and dynamic solution here 

Comment: you need to add controller in listview

Comment: Yes. The ListView needs a ScrollController(), but this controller has no method to get the total listview height.

Comment: itemExtent: 95 * entriesController.guestbookEntries.length; you will get the height

Comment: How I said. This seems more like a workaround instead of a real solution. I think it would be better to search a way to solve the issue itself. There must be a reason why the list works in principle, but no longer on hot reload. 